# How does KFold work when n_samples % n_splits is non-zero

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

Given the number of samples `n_samples` and `n_splits`, when `n_sample % n_splits == 0`, we can perform a well defined k-fold cross validation.

Surprisingly, when I accidentally set `n_samples = 40`, `n_splits = 14`, the `KFold` is still working, here is my code

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
import numpy as np

kf_test = KFold(n_splits=14)
test_x = np.random.rand(40)
pointer = 0
for item_t, item_v in kf_test.split(test_x):
    if pointer == 0:
        print(item_t.shape)
        print(item_v.shape)
        print(len(item_v) / 40)
    pointer += 1
pointer, test_x
```

How KFold is working when `n_samples % n_splits != 0`? I have tried different values but unable to find some pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says:

> The first n_samples % n_splits folds have size n_samples // n_splits + 1, other folds have size n_samples // n_splits, where n_samples is the number of samples.

In this case, the dataset is split into 14 folds, with 12 folds having 3 examples each, and 2 folds having 2 examples each.

You can see that with your code if you just remove the pointer variable.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
import numpy as np

kf_test = KFold(n_splits=14)
test_x = np.random.rand(40)
for item_t, item_v in kf_test.split(test_x):
    print(item_t.shape)
    print(item_v.shape)
    print(len(item_v) / 40)
# test_x
```